# Laravel query check if table column value exists

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Category table and in my RegistrationController i use the Category in another query, so i want another Query to check if cte_gender_id has 1, 2, and 3 as a value in the column.

**What i have right now:(in the RegistrationController)**

```
$category = Category::where('cte_distance_id', $distance_id)
  ->where('cte_gender_id', $gender_id);
if(is_null($categorie)){
  return back()->with("errorMessage", "Categorie not found");
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$gender_id = ['1', '2', '3'];

// If you suppose collection
$category = Category::where('cte_distance_id', $distance_id)
                    ->whereIn('cte_gender_id', $gender_id)->get();

if($category->isEmpty()){
    return back()->with("errorMessage", "Categorie not found");
}

// If you suppose single element
$category = Category::where('cte_distance_id', $distance_id)
                        ->whereIn('cte_gender_id', $gender_id)->first();

if($category){
    return back()->with("errorMessage", "Categorie not found");
}
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the quick answer! I tried it and there is no '3' in cte_gender_id in the categories but it still doesnt give the error. I tried the first collection of code

Comment: i only need to check on cte_gender_id if that is what you asked

Comment: You expect that this query will give you single element or array of elements?

Comment: oh, single  elements

Comment: so use case in my code: // If you suppose single element

Answer (score 0):

you can evaluate this way for both get and first methods:

```
if(!isset($category) || count($category) < 1){
    return back()->with("errorMessage", "Categorie not found");
}
```